# Bind a class collection property via xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemsource

This is my Globals class

```
public class Globals
{
    private static Globals instance = new Globals();

    protected Globals()
    {

    }

    public static Globals Instance
    {            
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public TrackList Tracklist = new TrackList();
}
```

This is TrackList in a smart code:

```
public class TrackList : SettingAttribute {
    public TrackList()
    {
        this.tracks = new ObservableCollectionExt<Track>();
    }

    protected ObservableCollectionExt<Track> tracks;

    public ObservableCollectionExt<Track> Tracks
    {
        get
        {
            return tracks;
        }
    }

    public class Track : ICloneable
    {
        protected Track()
        {
            // Track instance is achieved by GetTrack
        }

        public GetTrack(string path)
        {
            // code implementation here
        }
    }
}
```

I wish to bind Globals.Instance.Tracklist.Tracks in a ListView using XAML.

Via runtime, is really easy using ItemSource property

```
lv.ItemsSource = Globals.Instance.Tracklist.Tracks;
```

but using xaml I tried with several codes but none is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Tracklist.Tracks, Source={x:Static local:Globals.Instance}}"
```

Tracklist has to be a property. Change your Globals class to:

```
public class Globals
{
    private static Globals instance = new Globals();

    protected Globals()
    {
        Tracklist = new TrackList();
    }

    public static Globals Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public TrackList Tracklist { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you view model create Property with type Globals as follows:

```
    property Globals Globals {get;set;}
```

In XAML bind to it:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Globals.Instance.Tracklist.Tracks}">
```

Comment: Syned I follewed your solution and it works!

Thanks a lot for all the answers too.

Comment: @user1649247 Since the suggestion from user `@syned` worked for you, you may want to mark it as an `Answer`. It will help other readers of this post, as well.